# How can I merge multiple blobs with different shapes in Caffe?

Tags: caffe

I am trying to merge several bottom blobs into one top blob and then feed it to the next layer.
These blobs come from different convolution/FC layers, so their shape differ.
I tried concat layer, but using either axis 0 or 1, I get errors such as:

```
I1217 23:47:56.877848  9968 layer_factory.cpp:58] Creating layer concat_fuse2
I1217 23:47:56.878350  9968 net.cpp:100] Creating Layer concat_fuse2
I1217 23:47:56.878350  9968 net.cpp:434] concat_fuse2 <- relu4_relu4_0_split_1
I1217 23:47:56.878850  9968 net.cpp:434] concat_fuse2 <- relu5_relu5_0_split_1
I1217 23:47:56.879349  9968 net.cpp:434] concat_fuse2 <- relu6_relu6_0_split_0
I1217 23:47:56.879349  9968 net.cpp:408] concat_fuse2 -> fuse_4_6
F1217 23:47:56.879849  9968 concat_layer.cpp:42] Check failed: top_shape[j] == bottom[i]->shape(j) (32 vs. 16) All inputs must have the same shape, except at concat_axis.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

How should I go about this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caffe gives you the reason why this fails right in the error message:

> All inputs must have the same shape, except at concat_axis.

The reason for this is, that all data is stored in [Blobs](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html), which are *N*-dimensional arrays. The typical Blob for image data has four dimensions: number *N* x channel *K* x height *H* x width *W*. In a Blob, the width, height and number of channels must be the same. This means, all images in one batch have to have the same number of channels, width, and height.

The `Concat` is used to concatenate along either axis 0 (the number of images) or axis 1 (the channels). This means, that you can only concatenate inputs with the same height and width.

Now, I assume that you use only FC layers after that concatenated layers, as I don't think you can preserve spatial information well through such a concatenation. That means, to the network it doesn't make a difference if the input is a *H x W* image, or a *1 x HW* vector.

So, instead, you can use a `Reshape` layer to stack all information in the *K* dimension, i.e. the number of channels. So we go from the dimensions *N x K x H x W* to the dimensions *N x KHW x 1 x 1*. After you've done this on all input Blobs, you can easily use `Concat` along axis 1.

Comment: Thanks, prior to Concat, I should reshape all bottom blobs and then feed the resulting blobs to the Concat layer right? 
When they are concatenated, I can again use reshape to reshape it to the desired  spatial dimension? 
(by the way I guess axis 1 is the number of images and 0 is the channels)

Comment: Actually, axis 1 is the channels per image, and 0 is the number of images in a batch - as described in the link "Blobs" in the answer. Yes, you can reshape it to any dimension you like afterwards. However, I am not sure how you want to make sense of spatial relations when concatenating independent Conv and FC layers. As already written in the answer - if you only use FC layers afterwards, the dimensions don't matter at all.